# StringTokenizer com delimitador String não funciona

Tags: java, string, token

Eu tenho que usar um *string tokenizer* para dividir uma *string* em Java. o código está assim:

```
StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(palavra, "--");
```

Porém quando entro com a seguinte *string*:

```
1 - -- * d 2
```

O *split* reconhece o "-" como delimitador. logo me retorna como primeiro *token* o "1 ". Como fazer para ele reconhecer somente quando for "--" e não somente "-"

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Não use esta classe, ela é problemática, para casos simples é mais fácil usar [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) da `String` mesmo.

```
class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "1 - -- * d 2";
        String[] tokens = "1 - -- * d 2".split("--");
        for (String token : tokens) {
            System.out.println(token);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/j1Xwak). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Tokenizer). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/Tokenizer.java).